# Concatenate two SAS data sets, but only if ID appear in both

Tags: sas, concatenation

I want to concatenate two SAS data sets, one from 2003 and one from 2013. There is a uniq identifier in both, and I'll only allow allow records to be concatenated if they appears in both.

NB. there is multiple records with the same ID.

Comment: We need some context.  Please post the code you've tried so we can help. [check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score -1):

Here's some untested code:

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select * from(
select * from t1 where t1.id in (select t2.id in t2)
union
select * from t2 where t2.id in (select t1.id in t1)) as A;
quit;
```